# Simples??? How to set all fields in Excel spreadsheet to convert from lower-case to UPPER-CASE

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

I know this must sound like I have no idea what I'm doing. Older versions of Excel had a page/sheet function which could be set to ensure all fields in an Excel spreadsheet would automatically convert input (while typing) from lower-case to UPPER-CASE irrespective of how they were initially entered. Does anyone know the function/how to this set this without having to go into "macro-mode" or having to use "VB"...???

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/263580

Comment: without vba: you can try using Autocorrect replacing small letters to caps, but it is close to ridiculous!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've receive a comment on how to put the upper-case equivalent of the typed input into another cell with a formula. To replace the value in the cell itself you would require some form of VBA event macro. AFAIK, there has never been an automated upper case conversion but I can recall a couple of database products that did and form based input could do the same thing (through VBA parsing of the text).

If you want a VBA solution then right-click the worksheet's name tab and choose `View Code`. When the VBE opens up, paste the following into the pane titled something like *Book1 - Sheet1 (Code)*.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C2:M10")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo Fìn
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim c As Range
        For Each c In Intersect(Target, Range("C2:M10"))
            c = UCase(c.Value2)
        Next c
    End If
Fìn:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

You didn't supply any specifics so I imagined the input range as C2:M10. You should be able to modify that portion to a closer approximation of the range that the values are types or pasted into.

When you think you have the input range right, tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to your worksheet. Anything typed into that range will be converted to its uppercase equivalent.